# Error: Environment variable CTL_INIT_DIR or -d option must be specified

Tags: environment-variables, environment

The same code is giving the output when I execute manually,
but with cronjob the there is error to set the environment variable

```
/comptel/ilink/common/6.2/comptel_utilities/bin/ctl_control status > /comptel/ilink/health_check/ctl_status.txt

cat /comptel/ilink/health_check/ctl_status.txt
```

ctl_control status command output should be displayed.
instead there is

```
Error: Environment variable CTL_INIT_DIR or -d option must be specified
```

Comment: Can you give us some context? what is `/comptel/ilink` and where did you obtain it? Do you set `CTL_INIT_DIR` in your interactive environment? if so, where and how?

Comment: /comptel/ilink/common/6.2/comptel_utilities/bin/
this is path for the script :ctl_control status

Comment: I understand that - but it appears to be a private or closed-source script: without knowing more about it, there's really nothing much we can say apart from "set an appropriate cron environment"

Comment: how to set an appropriate cron environment

Comment: You add line(s) of the form `name = value` before the command (space around assignments is allowed in crontabs - unlike in most shell scripts) or move the command(s) to a script and set environment variables there in the usual way.